# React js export a variable

Tags: reactjs, formik

I want to receive a value from my variable(meta) in the file form.js
this one:

```
export const TextInput = ({ icon, ...props }) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  const [showpass, setShowpass] = useState(false);
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
    {'....'}
```

And I wanto to send it to the file login.js

```
// styled components
import {
  StyledTextInput,
  StyledFormArea,
  StyledFormButton,
  StyledLabel,
  Avatar,
  StyledTitle,
  colors,
  ButtonGroup,
  ExtraText,
  TextLink,
  CopyrightText,
  ErrorMsg
} from "../components/Styles";

import Logo from "./../assets/logo.png";

// formik
import { Formik, Form,useField } from "formik";
import  {TextInput} from "../components/FormLib";
import * as Yup from "yup";

//icons
import { FiMail, FiLock } from "react-icons/fi";
// Loader
import Loader from "react-loader-spinner";
// auth & redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../auth/actions/userActions";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthCode from 'react-auth-code-input';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

//pop up style.css 
import '../assets/css/popup.css'
// Import popup lib
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';



const Login = ({ loginUser}) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
  {......}
```

I know it may be a begginner question, but im not being able to figure out how to send this variable through files , by now thanks for the support
Some part of the login file where i want to check the variable

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(meta.error === 'codigo 2 fatores incorreto'){
    setShowPopup(true);
    }
  }, [meta.error])
```

As you can see I want to handle an pop up in the page login , but I need to get the meta variable to do this

Comment: Does the `Login` page have a formik form?

Comment: @Moistbobo yes it does have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create the onMetaChange property then use `useEffect` hook to pass the meta to the login form whenever meta is changed

like below

```
export const TextInput = ({onMetaChange, ...props}) => {
    const [field, meta] = useField()
    
    ...
   
    useEffect(() => {
        onMetaChange && onMetaChange(meta);
    }, [meta]) 

    ...
}
```

also note that this is not the best practice for doing this you can check code samples from the library you are using to find out what is the best practice and best style

Comment: I got it , but now its giving me an error :setshowpopup(true) -> Object(...) is not a function , do you know waht can I do to resolve it ?

Comment: create a new property with the name of `onMetaChange` then just add the useEffect Section to your TextInput component before the return and in the Login component use useState hook like this `const [meta, setMeta] = useState(null);` then add the property `onMetaChange` to your TextInput in your login component like this `<TextInput onMetaChange={setMeta} {...restOfProps}/>`

Comment: I don't know the exact problem but you are probably using an undefiend or an empty object to use a function and that is giving you the error you need to check if the variable is set at first. it could still be something else but its probably this

Comment: probably , but my meta.error is always changing, because of the yup lib and some validations that Im doing on the project , so... it cleans my fields always that I try to type something ,there is other way to correct the function error ?

Comment: you are probably returning the wrong type in your error handler check library official examples to find out what is the right way.

Comment: usually they don't just expect the error and they want the new value of field too